# Count the number of uppercase and lowercase letters for each item in an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, loops, count

I am attempting to write a function that counts the number of lowercase and uppercase letters per item in an array. Then create a new column in my original table to classify that instance as having more upper or lower case letters.

Here is my array:

```
[array([['MARZIA HAS LIGMA LWIAY #0044'],
   ['This Slinky Montage Is Bizarrely Satisfying to Watch'],
   ['MAKING HER DREAM COME TRUE! (MAKE A WISH)'],
   ...,
   ['THE EVOLUTION OF FORTNITE! 2011 - 2019'],
   ["India's trucks are works of art"],
   ['Several airlines change flight routes after Iranian missile downs American drone']],
  dtype=object)]
```

## function that i have

```
Upper=0
Lower=0
for c in range(len(dummy_array)):
    for i in c:
        if i.isupper():
            Upper +=1
        elif i.islower():
            Lower +=1
        else:
            pass

        if d[Upper] > d[Lower]:
            train_data["Caps_in_title"] = 1
        else:
            train_data["Caps_in_title"] = 0
print(Upper)
print(Lower)
```

Comment: and what is the question? is there any problem?

Comment: `c` is the array index, not the array element, so `for i in c:` makes no sense. You should use `for c in dummy_array:`, without `range(len(...))`

Comment: You have a multidimensional array nested inside a list. You need nested loops to get to the individual characters.

Comment: What does the variable `d` refer to?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "text" : [['MARZIA HAS LIGMA LWIAY #0044'],
       ['This Slinky Montage Is Bizarrely Satisfying to Watch'],
       ['MAKING HER DREAM COME TRUE! (MAKE A WISH)'],
       ['THE EVOLUTION OF FORTNITE! 2011 - 2019'],
       ["India's trucks are works of art"],
       ['Several airlines change flight routes after Iranian missile downs American drone']]
})

def character_case_ratio(xs):
    """
    function to count number of upper and lowercase letters and compare there ratio
    """
    upper_count = len([x for x in xs[0] if (x.isupper() and x.isalpha())])
    lower_count = len([x for x in xs[0] if (x.islower() and x.isalpha())])

    if upper_count > lower_count:
        return 1
    return 0

# apply the function above over your input text, and create a new column in the DataFrame
df["case_ratio"] = df["text"].apply(character_case_ratio)
```

Output:

```
    text                                                case_ratio
0   [MARZIA HAS LIGMA LWIAY #0044]                      1
1   [This Slinky Montage Is Bizarrely Satisfying t...   0
2   [MAKING HER DREAM COME TRUE! (MAKE A WISH)]         1
3   [THE EVOLUTION OF FORTNITE! 2011 - 2019]            1
4   [India's trucks are works of art]                   0
5   [Several airlines change flight routes after I...   0
```